Content-Security-Policy header manipulation in ASP.NET MVC
In a ASP.NET MVC project I need to manipulate response headers to add nonce for Content-Security-Policy. I've tried this in Startup.cs:
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new SielUserIdProvider());
        app.MapSignalR();

        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            string nonce = null;
            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                var nonceBytes = new byte[32];
                rng.GetBytes(nonceBytes);
                nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(nonceBytes);
            }
            context.Set("ScriptNonce", nonce);
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",
                new[] { string.Format("script-src 'self' 'nonce-{0}'", nonce) });
            return next();
        });
    }

and it works, but I'd like to use the customHeaders specified in Web.config and replace in Startup.cs the nonce value for Content-Security-Policy existing header rather than add a new one. Though, I've noticed that at this point in context.Response.Headers I can't see the headers added via Web.config.
Any idea to solve this?
